# How do I find out if I still have citizenship in a country (Romania)?

Tags: citizenship, romania

I was born in another country (Romania) and moved to the US but I haven't been back in a while and out of curiosity I wanted to know if I still have citizenship.

I found a website (https://romaniancitizenship.ro/services/proof-romanian-citizenship/) but really can't tell if it's an official website or not.

Is there any more official way to check or a way to tell whether the site is real?

Comment: Being a Romanian citizen makes you a citizen of the European Union. That might make it worthwhile to get everything documented. Apply for a new passport and they will tell you what documents you need to show.

Comment: "really can't tell if it's an official website or not": the "about us" page in the site menu describes the site owner as a law firm, so it is definitely not an official site of the Romanian government.

Comment: The most important facts would be the nationality of your mother and father, next where you were born, and next your age. So three out of four important items are missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply moved to the US, nothing more, then nothing would have disturbed your Romanian citizenship. Even if you became a US citizen and officially renounced your Romanian citizenship, under the Romanian constitution Art 5(2) "Romanian citizenship cannot be withdrawn if acquired by birth". It's yours for life.

Comment: Yes, but Romania [doesn't have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_nationality_law) "jus soli", so "acquired by birth" means more than just being born there, which is all we know from OP's post.